# SimpleJdbcCall can't find a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, spring, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute an oracle procedure stored on my database, I've executed it sometimes but after renaming it or changing some parameters i can't execute it from spring anymore.

I defined it like this (body and spec):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PTR_GRUPOS_TRABAJO
AS
   PROCEDURE UDPATE_DIA (
--some parameters here
);
```

And i create the SimpleJdbcCall like this:

```
pActualizaDia = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withCatalogName("PTR_GRUPOS_TRABAJO").withProcedureName("UPDATE_DIA");
```

After setting (properly) every parameter it fails. I've tried even setting withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess and declaring each parameter, but although this time i get every ? (parameter) in my query, it still complains about not finding the procedure, like this.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call PTR_GRUPOS_TRABAJO.UPDATE_DIA()}];
```

What is wrong? Thank you

Comment: If your stored procedure requires parameters (as you SP definition seems to suggest it does), I can't see where you are supplying them. Perhaps this is where your error is?

Comment: No, as said, i'm setting them, i exclude the code, because the issue isn't there, the proc. isnt found, if there were a parameter missmatching spring says it. It can not achieve metadata. Just like if there were no procedure at all.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance of the intracacies of Spring, but if you don't know where the error is, how can you say with authority that the issue is not with the parameter declaration? It may well not be, but surely it would be best to put all the code you are using to call the SP in the post and let someone with a better understanding (probably not me though) make that judgement?

Comment: When there is a parameter missmatching Exception trace says it explicitly with PL error code PLS-306 not PLS-302 which is the one i get. Anyway i didnt want to be rude, if i was im sorry, but my english is a bit poor and it maybe sound unpolite. Next time i'll put all the code anyway, i was just trying to make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right...

the database procedure was called UDPATE_DIA instead of UPDATE_DIA. It was a given procedure and I'm a bit dyslexic.

Thank you Ollie anyway, I deserve death and destruction.

Comment: Not at all my friend. That sort of procedure name mixup does happen and it's so difficult to spot. Glad you found the answer in the end.